# Simulating breaking bonds in molecular dynamics

Tags: molecular-dynamics, chemical-compounds

How does one introduce the possibility of breaking a bond in a molecule during MD simulation?

I only found the cases when we just introduce the harmonic potential $U_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}k(r_i - r_j)^2$ for atoms in a molecule or introduce an additional equation restricting the length of a bond during simulaton.

Nevertheless, it is still not clear for me how we can take into account the breaking bond result?

Comment: This question would probably fit better on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/#)

Comment: There is also a molecular-dynamics tag on MMSE.

Comment: Thanks, I asked the question  [there](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/751/simulating-breaking-bonds-in-molecular-dynamics)